# in Skia, convert rgba raw data to a skBitmap

Tags: skia

Say if I have a rgba frame raw data in memory, is there a way to convert it to a skBitmap?  so that I can use other skia operation to draw on this frame.  This case is using C++.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at SkSurface::MakeRasterDirect()